integrals over dyadic intervals implies function is constant
For each natural number $n\geq 1$, consider the dyadic intervals partitioning the unit interval $$I_n^1=[0,1/2^{n}], ~~J_n^1=[1/2^{n},2\cdot 1/2^{n}]$$
$$I_n^2=[2\cdot 1/2^{n},3\cdot 1/2^{n}], ~~J_n^2=[3\cdot 1/2^{n},4\cdot 1/2^{n}]$$
$$...$$
$$I_n^{2^{n-1}}=[(2^{n}-2)\cdot 1/2^{n},(2^{n}-1)\cdot 1/2^{n}], ~~J_n^{2^{n-1}}=[(2^{n}-1)\cdot 1/2^{n},1]$$
If $f\in L^2([0,1],\mathbb{R})$, and if $$\int_{I_n^k}f d\lambda=\int_{J_n^k}fd\lambda$$
for all $k,n$, how do I show $f$ is constant a.e.?
Motivation: trying to prove that the functions $$\{\mathbb{1}_{I_n^k}-\mathbb{1}_{J_n^k} \}\cup \{\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}\}$$ form a hilbert basis for $L^2$.

I guess $k$ should run from $1$ to $2^{n-1}$ since there are total $2^n$ subintervals for each $n$, and consequently, the last ones should be $I^{2^{n-1}}_n$ and $J^{2^{n-1}}_n$, not $I^n_n$ and $J_n^n$.

yes thank you @SangchulLee

Let us write $D^k_n = [\frac{k-1}{2^n}, \frac{k}{2^n}]$, so that $I^k_n = D^{2k-1}_n$ and $J^k_n = D^{2k}_n$. Then it is easy to check that
$$ I_n^k + J_n^k = D^{2k-1}_{n+1} + D^{2k}_{n+1} = D^k_n $$
for all $n \geq 0$ and $1 \leq k \leq 2^n$. In particular,
$$ \langle f, \mathbf{1}_{D_n^k} \rangle = \frac{1}{2^n} \langle f, \mathbf{1} \rangle $$
for all admissible $n$ and $k$, where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denotes the inner product of $L^2([0, 1])$. Consequently, the following identity holds for almost all $x \in [0, 1]$:
\begin{align*}
\langle f, \mathbf{1} \rangle = \sum_{k=1}^{2^n} 2^n \langle f, \mathbf{1}_{D^k_n} \rangle \mathbf{1}_{D^k_n} (x)
\end{align*}
In light of this equality, it suffices to prove the following general claim:

Lemma. Let $D_n^k$ be as above, and define the operator $T_n : L^2([0,1]) \to L^2([0, 1])$ by
$$ T_n f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{2^n} 2^n \langle f, \mathbf{1}_{D^k_n} \rangle \mathbf{1}_{D^k_n} (x). $$
Then for each $f \in L^2([0,1])$, we have $T_n f \to f$ in $L^2$. In other words, the dyadic approximation of $f$ converges to $f$ itself in $L^2$ as $n\to\infty$.

This lemma can be proved by invoking the "standard machine", which we illustrate for the self-containedness.
Proof of Lemma. First, note that $(\mathbf{1}_{D^k_n})_{1\leq k\leq 2^n}$ is a family or orthogonal functions for each $n$. So by the Pythagorean theorem,
\begin{align*}
\| T_n f \|^2
&= \left\| \sum_{k=1}^{2^n} 2^n \langle f, \mathbf{1}_{D^k_n} \rangle \mathbf{1}_{D^k_n}\right\|^2
= \sum_{k=1}^{2^n} \left| 2^n \langle f, \mathbf{1}_{D^k_n} \rangle \right|^2 \left\|  \mathbf{1}_{D^k_n} \right\|^2
= \sum_{k=1}^{2^n} 2^n \left| \langle f, \mathbf{1}_{D^k_n} \rangle \right|^2.
\end{align*}
Then by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{2^n} 2^n \left| \langle f, \mathbf{1}_{D^k_n} \rangle \right|^2
\leq \sum_{k=1}^{2^n} 2^n \|f\|^2 \|\mathbf{1}_{D^k_n}\|^2
= \|f\|^2.
\end{align*}
This tells that $T_n$ is a bounded operator with the operator norm satisfying $\|T\| \leq 1$. Moreover, if $g \in C([0, 1])$, then it is easy to prove that $T_n g \to g$ uniformly on $[0, 1]$.
Now let $f \in L^2([0, 1])$ and $g \in C([0, 1])$ be arbitrary. Then
\begin{align*}
\| T_n f - f \|
&\leq \| T_n f - T_n g \| + \| T_n g - g \| + \| f - g \| \\
&\leq 2\| f - g \| + \| T_n g - g \|.
\end{align*}
Taking $\limsup$ as $n \to \infty$, this gives
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{n\to\infty} \| T_n f - f \|
\leq 2\| f - g \|.
\end{align*}
Since the left-hand side does not depend on $g$ and $C([0, 1])$ is a dense subset of $L^2([0, 1])$, letting $g \to f$ in $L^2$ shows that
$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \| T_n f - f \| = 0, $$
which is precisely what we want. $\square$
